# Laravel Snippets (v.1.13.0): Problems with relationships (One-To-Many, ...)

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, relationship

**Introduction**
I'm using this Add-on for Visual Studio Code.
When creating relations with it. My views seem not working. I get an error in the browser (see below).

> Laravel Snippets ID: onecentlin.laravel5-snippets Beschreibung:
> Laravel snippets for Visual Studio Code  (Support Laravel 5 and above)
> Version: 1.13.0 Herausgeber: Winnie Lin Link zum Visual Studio
> Marketplace: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=onecentlin.laravel5-snippets

**My Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Person extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [];

    /**
     * Get the phone associated with the Person
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
     */
    public function phone(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Phone::class);
    }
}
```

**Error shown by the browser, when calling the view**

> TypeError Return value of App\Models\Person::phone() must be an instance of
> App\Models\HasOne, instance of
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne returned (View:
> C:\Users\MusaSaglam\componenttest\resources\views\test\index.blade.php)

**My view**

```
<x-layout>

    <main class="main" id="top">
      <div class="container" data-layout="container">
        <script>
          var isFluid = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('isFluid'));
          if (isFluid) {
            var container = document.querySelector('[data-layout]');
            container.classList.remove('container');
            container.classList.add('container-fluid');
          }
        </script>
  
        <x-nav.admin-nav/>
        <div class="content">
            <x-nav.admin-nav-top/>

            <h1>People</h1>
            @foreach ($people as $person)
                <h2>{{ $person->id }}</h2>
                <h2>{{ $person->phone->number }}</h2>
            @endforeach


        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </x-layout>
```

But if I remove **: HasOne** after *public function phone()* in my model. Everything works fine.

**Two questions**

- Why does the Snippet adds **: HasOne**. What is the benefit of this?
- Does not make it easier for users like me using the snippet without **: HasOne**?
  I'm a beginner and I could not understand why the tutorials did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can refer to the type declaration https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php**

1. Why does the Snippet add: HasOne. What is the benefit of this?

- It’s the return type of method and it’s standard so the VS code add-on is giving you the snippet(code) which follows the industry standards.

2. Does not make it easier for users like me using the snippet without : HasOne? I'm a beginner and I could not understand why the tutorials did not work.

- This snippet will work don’t worry about it. Just declare the **HasOne** before the class initialization like `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne` and it should work.

**By the way type hinting is optional so a snippet will work if you just remove :HasOne(return type of method). which you already tried.**

Comment: Perfect. After declaring it and (rewriting it after the function) everything works as it should be. And thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Happy Coding :)